# CSS is loading from SCSS instead of CSS

Tags: sass, gulp

I have integrated sass in Magento project with a gulp. Whenever I fired a command gulp watch, everything is working perfected and `app.css` is generated. But when I access the page, for a while all css style is loading from `app.css` after that css is applied from `.scss` files. I am not able to find the solution for this.

FYI - Above scenario is occurring when I disable the option for Enable SouceMap. When I enable the option sourcemap, css applying from `.scss` files.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you interpreted sass, you must have to pre-compile to make the changes, in compilation process all the scss files will copied into css files and will load as css but fortunately Magento auto does this task for you.

Have you followed the guide lines from here
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/gulp-sass.html